# How to make my drawing move inside HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas and Javascript. How can I make it move like move it's arms and feet?

I tried Googling for some tutorials but failed.

Attached here is my image and my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="canvascss.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="300px" >
        Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas element
    </canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext("2d")) { // Check HTML5 canvas support
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get Canvas Context object

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "black"; // #ffe4c4
    context.arc(200, 50, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // draw circle for head
    context.fill();

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; // color
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.arc(200, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI, false); // draw semicircle for smiling
    context.stroke();

    // eyes
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "black"; // color
    context.arc(190, 45, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // draw left eye
    context.fill();
    context.arc(210, 45, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // draw right eye
    context.fill();

    // body
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(200, 80);
    context.lineTo(200, 180);
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();

    // arms
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; // blue
    context.moveTo(200, 80);
    context.lineTo(150, 130);
    context.moveTo(200, 80);
    context.lineTo(250, 130);
    context.stroke();

    // legs
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.moveTo(200, 180);
    context.lineTo(150, 280);
    context.moveTo(200, 180);
    context.lineTo(250, 280);
    context.stroke();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You may want to modify your title.  You aren't actually trying to make the canvas itself move, but stuff within the canvas.

Comment: Aw, thanks @Eclecticist. Will modify the title now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HTML5 Canvas Animation with requestAnimFrame](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/):

> To create an animation using HTML5 Canvas, we can use the
>   requestAnimFrame shim which enables the browser to determine the
>   optimal FPS for our animation.  For each animation frame, we can
>   update the elements on the canvas, clear the canvas, redraw the
>   canvas, and then request another animation frame.

In short your point of departure is the following:

```
requestAnimationFrame
```

You will need a javascript function to CHANGE aspects of your starting image, and then to call that javascript code at regular intervals.

`setInterval` is another key word to google and learn from.

Comment: Thanks @Gamemorize! Can I make a button where when I clicked "start", it will start moving, then when I cicked "Stop", it will then stop.

Comment: certainly, you will need your animation function to be inside an onclick event see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Yeheyyy, Thanks again, you're an angel! :)

Comment: You are welcome. To help others find this question remember to accept the answer. Have fun animating!

Comment: @kris: *"Can I make a button where when I clicked "start", it will start moving..."* - please try to avoid asking questions like this. Its really not related to your issue of moving the stick figure. If desired, please ask a new question. (This helps the site use questions/answers as a canonical answer to other similar questions).